# ¿Cómo actualizar la fecha de modificación basándome en otros campos?

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (
    `A`,
    `B`,
    `C`,
    `D`,
    `E`,
    `lastupdated`
)
VALUES 
    '1', '1231', '99.99', '', '', NOW()
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `lastupdated` = IF(
        `C` != VALUES(`C`) OR
        `D` != VALUES(`D`) OR
        `E` != VALUES(`E`),
        NOW(),
        `lastupdated`
    ),
    `C` = VALUES(`C`),
    `D` = VALUES(`D`),
    `E` = VALUES(`E`)
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que se actualice el campo `lastupdated` solo cuando los demás campos han sido modificados, de lo contrario quiero que permanezca con la fecha actual (sin modificar).

La tabla tiene una PK compuesta de `` (`A`, `B`) ``. Por lo tanto, cuando `A` y `B` existen se actualizan los campos `C`, `D`, y `E`. Hasta ahí todo funciona perfecto, pero, la parte en la cual comparo los valores actuales con los que están siendo insertados para decidir si uso `NOW()` o no parace no funcionar:

```
 `lastupdated` = IF(
    `C` != VALUES(`C`) OR
    `D` != VALUES(`D`) OR
    `E` != VALUES(`E`),
    NOW(),
    `lastupdated`
),
```

El campo `lastupdated` nunca se modifica a la fecha actual del `NOW()` a pesar de que estoy modificando manualmente el campo `C` para forzarlo.

¿Alguna idea de lo que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente decidí tomar otro camino. Modifiqué el campo `lastupdated` para que sea del tipo `TIMESTAMP` y que se actualice automáticamente cuando el registro se edite:

```
ALTER TABLE tabla
  CHANGE COLUMN lastupdated lastupdated timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Funciona como esperaba y `lastupdated` solo se actualiza cuando detecta cambios en los campos `C`, `D` y/o `E`.

El query se reduce finalmente a:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (
    `A`,
    `B`,
    `C`,
    `D`,
    `E`,
    `lastupdated`
)
VALUES 
    '1', '1231', '99.99', '', '', NOW()
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `C` = VALUES(`C`),
    `D` = VALUES(`D`),
    `E` = VALUES(`E`)
```